# Solution to a special differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, laplacian

I am wondering whether the following differential equation can be solved.

$$\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial y^2}+ \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial z^2}+ \alpha \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = g,$$

where $f= f(x,y,z,t)$, $\alpha$ is a constant and $g=g(x,y,z,t)$ is a given continuous function. This equation is similar to the heat equation except for function $g$.

Is there any analytic solution for this kind of equation? If not, what is the appropriate numerical method to solve it?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

The equation is called inhomogeneous heat equation.

If and how a analytical solution can be obtained is depending on the domain $(x,y,z)\in\Omega$, the boundary conditions the initial data and $g$. Especially the following cases are noteworthy

$\Omega=\mathbb{R}^3$: Use the fourier transform in the space domain.

$\Omega$ is a cuboid: Use a separation ansatz for the space domain which (for suitable boundary conditions) results in a sum over sine and cosine functions.

Additionally, it is possible to solve via fundamental solution but depending on the domain it might be hard to achieve.

Hope that helps.